# Hazelcast client is not reconnecting

Tags: java, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

In my application I using Hazelcast two clients and one server, everything till now is working properly but when machine goes to sleep and after starting machine clients tries to reconnect to the server but one client get connected and second tries to connect 2 times and fails:

```
Received auth from Connection[id=3, /192.168.0.6:5701->/192.168.0.6:5704, qualifier=null, endpoint=[192.168.0.6]:5704, alive=true, connectionType=JVM, planeIndex=-1], successfully authenticated, clientUuid: e99c4f2e-efe2-4bf7-93f8-1910ffdcf241, client version: 4.2 

2021-07-12 17:09:37.356  INFO 8060 --- [ration.thread-3] c.h.c.i.p.t.AuthenticationMessageTask    : [192.168.0.6]:5701 [APP] [4.2] Received auth from Connection[id=4, /192.168.0.6:5701->/192.168.0.6:5705, qualifier=null, endpoint=[192.168.0.6]:5705, alive=true, connectionType=JVM, planeIndex=-1], successfully authenticated, clientUuid: e99c4f2e-efe2-4bf7-93f8-1910ffdcf241, client version: 4.2
[{taskList=[{recurid=17, timeschedulerid=57, status=RUNNING}, {recurid=21, timeschedulerid=61, status=RUNNING}], taskcount=2, type=worker, uniqueid=4bbcda77-3286-4828-939a-a277ddda46a2}, {taskList=[{recurid=18, timeschedulerid=58, status=RUNNING}], taskcount=1, type=worker, uniqueid=e99c4f2e-efe2-4bf7-93f8-1910ffdcf241}]

2021-07-12 17:09:37.396  INFO 8060 --- [.IO.thread-in-0] c.h.i.server.tcp.TcpServerConnection     : [192.168.0.6]:5701 [APP] [4.2] Connection[id=4, /192.168.0.6:5701->/192.168.0.6:5705, qualifier=null, endpoint=[192.168.0.6]:5705, alive=false, connectionType=JVM, planeIndex=-1] closed. Reason: Connection closed by the other side
[{taskList=[{recurid=17, timeschedulerid=57, status=RUNNING}, {recurid=21, timeschedulerid=61, status=RUNNING}], taskcount=2, type=worker, uniqueid=4bbcda77-3286-4828-939a-a277ddda46a2}, {taskList=[{recurid=18, timeschedulerid=58, status=RUNNING}], taskcount=1, type=worker, uniqueid=e99c4f2e-efe2-4bf7-93f8-1910ffdcf241}]
Transfer Size
0
2021-07-12 17:09:37.703  WARN 8060 --- [.IO.thread-in-1] c.h.i.server.tcp.TcpServerConnection     : [192.168.0.6]:5701 [APP] [4.2] Connection[id=2, /127.0.0.1:5701->/127.0.0.1:5703, qualifier=null, endpoint=[127.0.0.1]:5703, alive=false, connectionType=JVM, planeIndex=-1] closed. Reason: Exception in Connection[id=2, /127.0.0.1:5701->/127.0.0.1:5703, qualifier=null, endpoint=[127.0.0.1]:5703, alive=true, connectionType=JVM, planeIndex=-1], thread=hz.APP1.IO.thread-in-1

java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0-262]
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0-262]
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223) ~[na:1.8.0-262]
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:197) ~[na:1.8.0-262]
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:377) ~[na:1.8.0-262]
        at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioInboundPipeline.process(NioInboundPipeline.java:119) ~[hazelcast-all-4.2.jar!/:4.2]
        at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.processSelectionKey(NioThread.java:383) [hazelcast-all-4.2.jar!/:4.2]
        at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.processSelectionKeys(NioThread.java:368) [hazelcast-all-4.2.jar!/:4.2]
        at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.selectLoop(NioThread.java:294) [hazelcast-all-4.2.jar!/:4.2]
        at com.hazelcast.internal.networking.nio.NioThread.executeRun(NioThread.java:249) [hazelcast-all-4.2.jar!/:4.2]
        at com.hazelcast.internal.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:102) [hazelcast-all-4.2.jar!/:4.2]
```

Why it is not reconnecting and getting closed and why it is trying to connect twice

Comment: Is this issue is fixed ?

Comment: Yes, it worked for me but it's not straight way I have to make many changes such as reuse address setting , increasing heartbeat and interval timeout, changes to the some of the listeners which I have created etc.